# How can I serve a React app from our server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This is more of a high-level question.

I want to make an "Intercom like" app -- that is, the app is loaded through a unique script tag URL from our server, and is then run on the client page.

My question is, on a high-level, how would I go about doing this?

For example, if the client page has an organization id (like Intercom does), then on the server are we just generating a JS file with that id and serving that? If so, how do we auto-generate this file? I'm a bit confused about how it all fits together and any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking about Server Side Rendering?

Comment: No, not really -- I'm talking about serving some unique JS code from a server which loads client side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a node js server, build your react app & serve it.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve the static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Okay sure, but how do we make sure that app itself serves the content relevant to the organization id?

Comment: @ColinRicardo you would change the `app.get("*")` means "all" to `app.get("/organizationID")` ?

Comment: Okay, but how would the file being served be actually customized to that organization id?

Comment: @ColinRicardo `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'organizationID/client/build/index.html'));`